# How can i get tags for multiple imag views with Touches moved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to get the imageView tags from touches moved.I have 10 imageviews and tags are from 1 to 10.I need to get the imageView tags when moved my finger over the images.

I can able to get this by,

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

                    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view] ;
                    CGRect fingerRect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 1, 1);


                    for(UIImageView *view in self.view.subviews)
                    {
                        CGRect subviewFrame = view.frame;

                        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(fingerRect, subviewFrame))
                         {
                            //we found the finally touched view
                         }
                    }
}
```

But i dont want to use `for` loop. Is there any other alternate to get the imageView which is below my move?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
UIView* touchedView = [self.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
```

With this location, you get a touchedView, in your case is UIImageView.

Comment: This will only work if the views do not overlap. When they overlap, it will return the top-most view.